# Connect arduino to server w/ GSM shield

Tags: arduino, server, live

For a project with a RC car, I want to send live data to a hosted website. It is digital data and it needs to be live on the website. Therefore, I need to use the 3G network to connect with the server. I searched on Google how to do that, but it was only about people with an ethernet shield.
could someone please help me?
If you want more info, please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a configuration similar to the one you've described to monitor and manage hydroponic facilities remotely.

In my case, I used an [Adafruit FONA](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module/overview) shield. I bought a SIM from my cell carrier (T-Mobile) that let's the FONA communicate on 2G. It costs me $10 a month. The FONA is connected to an Arduino Mega 2560 and I've got code on it that receives SMS messages (e.g. from my phone), processes them and sends me back response data.

If you'd like to see the code I'd be happy to share it.

-Tyler